# sum of logarithms with a constant equals $3n(n+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone help me with this? I've been trying to solve this for some time, but can't come up with a conclusion.

> Define constant $a$, when $\log_2(a)+\log_2(a)^2+\log_2(a)^3 + \cdots + \log_2(a)^n = 3n(n+1)$ and $n=1, 2, 3, \cdots$.

Comment: Hint:  use the fact that $\log_2 a^k=k\log_2 a$.

Comment: Didn't he specify the exponent outside the logarithm or is it a typo?

Comment: @rzkrd $\log_2(a)^n\equiv\log_2(a^n)\not\equiv\left(\log_2(a)\right)^n$

Comment: Remark (similar to rzkrd's): I understand that $\log_2(a)^2= (\log_2(a))\cdot (\log_2(a))$ . If you mean $\log_2(a^2)$ you should write it this way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Recall that

- $\log_a b + \log_a c = \log_a bc$
- $\log_ab^c = c\log_ab$
- $k^a \cdot k^b = k ^ {a + b}$

So,

$$\begin{align}\log_2(a)+\log_2(a)^2+\log_2(a)^3 + \cdots + \log_2(a)^n &= \log_2(a\cdot a^2\cdot a^3\cdots a^n) \\ &= \log_2(a^{1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n}) \\ &= (1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n)\log_2(a) \\ &= \left(\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^n i\right)\log_2(a)\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If interpreted as written in the OP we have to solve

$$\sum _{k=1}^n (\log(a))^k=\frac{\log (a) \left(\log ^n(a)-1\right)}{\log (a)-1}=  3n(n+1)$$

This is an algebraic equation of degree $n+1$ for the function $\log(a(n))$.

Numerically the first few values of the function $a(n)$ at integers $n$ are

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a(n)\\
 1 & 403.429 \\
 2 & 43.467 \\
 3 & 18.3453 \\
 4 & 11.702 \\
 5 & 8.89129 \\
 6 & 7.38906 \\
 7 & 6.46746 \\
 8 & 5.84875 \\
 9 & 5.40631 \\
 10 & 5.07484 \\
\end{array}
$$

The function can be fitted with two parameters $A$ and $B$ approximately by

$$a(n) \simeq A e^{e^{-B n}}$$